# import google/protobuf/timestamp.proto was not found or had errors in windows

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I am trying to generate C# code using .proto file, but getting error

***import google/protobuf/timestamp.proto*** was not found or had errors. windows

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "icigcppubsub1";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message SomeMessage {

    message Itemkey {
        string itemType = 1;
        string itemNo = 2;
    }

    message Locale {
        string countryCode = 1;
        string languageCode = 2;
    }

    message Names {
        Locale locale = 1;
        string itemName = 2;
        string presentationGroupCode = 3;
        string measurementSystem = 4;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp sourceInsertDateTime = 5;
        google.protobuf.Timestamp sourceUpdateDateTime = 6;
    }

    Itemkey itemKey = 1;
    repeated Names names = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

The error is produced because the protoc executable expects its libraries in particular locations (in the same folder, or in the ..\include).

**Solution**

Follow the following steps.

**STEP 1.** Install below package.

[image: Image showing Google.Protobuf and Google.Protobuf.Tools nuget packages]

**STEP 2.** Copy the Path of `Google.Protobuf.Tools`

[[image: Shows the Path to the Google.Protobuf.Tools executable2]

**STEP 3.** Copy the `protoc.exe` file from below folder path
`C:\Users\manishkumar\.nuget\packages\google.protobuf.tools\3.20.1\tools\windows_x64`

and Paste to

`C:\Users\manishkumar.ma\.nuget\packages\google.protobuf.tools\3.20.1\tools`

**STEP 4.** Change Execution path in command prompt.

[image]

**STEP 5.** Execute below command using .proto file

```
protoc -I="C:\Users\manishkumar\source\repos\protobuf_consoleApp" --csharp_out="C:\Users\manishkumar\source\repos\protobuf_consoleApp" "C:\Users\manishkumar\source\repos\protobuf_consoleApp\proto\*.proto"
```

[image]

Comment: Would love to see some breakdown of what the true problem actually was.